# Rails paths leading to domain with "ude" instead of "localhost"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

For some reason when I test, all my paths and link lead to a domain of "ude" rather than the usual localhost. Where should I start to dig to figure this out?

Comment: Can you paste here how do run the app

Comment: What testing framework do you use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you check your *environments/test.rb, environments/development* and make sure the following is set to the URL you want :

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'DESIRED URL'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change your domain name by using the following command in your terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts

##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.56.2   qruqsp.local









                               [ Read 10 lines ]
^G Get Help  ^O WriteOut  ^R Read File ^Y Prev Page ^K Cut Text  ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^J Justify   ^W Where Is  ^V Next Page ^U UnCut Text^T To Spell
```

change 127.0.0.1 to localhost instead of ude in your case

Refresh DNS settings with `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

Now `rails server` will work now with http://localhost:3000/

Also you can change it to anything you like for example

add a line in `127.0.0.1 www.rubyrails.com`

and refresh the DNS setting with `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

Now `rails server` will run in http://www.rubyrails.com:3000/

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what exactly your getting @stackjlei

Comment: I have everything except `192.168.56.2   qruqsp.local`. Does that part matter?

Comment: When I run `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` it just asks for my password. Is anything else suppose to show int he logs?

Answer (score 1):

Use the url helpers that end in _path (relative) instead of _url (absolute)